# BNF syntax for simple mini language

Tags: bnf

It's been about 20 yrs since college, LOL, but I've finally come across the need for a simple mini-parser. Remembered BNF from school haha and then a top down recursive parser or something like that. So i'm trying to model my mini language in BNF... some non-sensical examples of what I'm going for:

```
length > 5
(length > 5)
(length > 5) or (length < 2)
((length > 5) and (length < 7)) or length = 0
not (length > 5)
```

you can basically have an expression with or without parantheses, stack 'em with and/or or preface them with not. Obviously, certain things don't make sense like an or at the beginning, etc.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
<syntax>                 :: <not> <expressionSyntax> | <expressionSyntax>
<not>                    :: "not"
<expressionSyntax>       :: "(" <expression> ")" <expressionRepeatSyntax> | <expression> <expressionRepeatSyntax>
<expressionRepeatSyntax> :: ( <andOr> <expressionSyntax> )*
<andOr>             :: "and" | "or"
<expression>             :: need to finish this...
```

syntax is the leading not or without it, expressionSyntax is the expression with optional parantheses and the optional stacking of expressions.

Am I on the right track here? One thing that definitely doesn't look right is that I can't stack not expressions with this grammar:

not (length > 5) and not (length > 7)

Since it seems like you can only have one not in the beginning with my first pass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that grammar would work the way you want.

check out this tutorial, which goes over the BNF grammar for boolean expressions in detail http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor6.txt. An example from the first page:

```
 <b-expression>::= <b-term> [<orop> <b-term>]*
 <b-term>      ::= <not-factor> [AND <not-factor>]*
 <not-factor>  ::= [NOT] <b-factor>
 <b-factor>    ::= <b-literal> | <b-variable> | (<b-expression>)
```

It may not contain the exact grammar you want in cut-and-paste-ready form, but it should have the information you need to create it.